# Long running PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, soap, soap-client

I have a long running PHP script that makes soap request to a remote server and then makes SQL query executions based on it responses. The script works fine when the volume of the amount of data I am getting and setting into SQL is around ~1000 rows or so with MySQL 5.5. When I try to do more (like 10,000+) I get:

```
<!-- SHTML Wrapper - 500 Server Error -->
```

[an error occurred while processing this directive]

as a response in my browser after around ~15 minutes every single time. I am trying to find a solution for completing my whole script without creating chunks of scripts. Before running any other SQL query I execute

```
SET SESSION wait_timeout = 9999
```

What would be causing this problem? Are there any value timeout value in my php.ini I should set differently? Is there anything else I can do? Note that all error reporting is set to display.

Comment: If an operation is going to take more than a few seconds, you generally don't want to do it within a web process. It's wasteful of server RAM space, and if the user aborts you'll end up with an error. Much better to put this on a cron or a background job.

Comment: try to wrap the queries to StoredProcedures. this will increase performance at 50%, also check if you have the indexes for the tables

Comment: @halfer if I shell execute it as a cron will I be able to get a response for a web page somehow?

Comment: Yes. If you use cron you'd generally have a `queue` table of all the things that need processing, and you can store the primary key in the web app session. The web app can make a status enquiry call using this key by reading the table and seeing if any changes have been made. The cron system should process the queue items in order, and when an item is processed it should mark it as completed (together with any results) by writing to the queue row. The app can then examine this on its next status enquiry.

Comment: This is basically what queue systems do - if you have full server control you can look into Gearman or [many others](http://queues.io/) if you wish.